# Power bi Gantt Chart, displaying milstones

Tags: powerbi

I have a Gantt chart. I want to put some icon in the chart, if the task is a milestone. 
Is there any way to do this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What visualisation are you using for the Gantt?

Comment: Gantt chart, from the custom visuals.

Answer (score 0):

The custom Gantt visual does not have a milestone feature. You'd need to insert a Milestone as a separate task (row of data) with a duration of one day.